# how define programmaticaly if app is run on iphone 5

Tags: xcode, height, scale

I work on image scaling. How to find out if app is run on iphone 5? Need to know if screen height is 960 or 1136..

Answer (score 3):

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)

if (IS_IPHONE5) {
    NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
} else {
    NSLog(@"iphone 4s or lower");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the height of screen

```
int height =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
if(height > 480){
    NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"iPhone 4, 4s....");
}
```

Comment: If you run that on an iPad, it will return thinking it is iPhone 5.

Comment: @theLastNightTrain actually the question is related only for iPhone that's why i answer only for iPhone

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`+[UIScreen mainScreen]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) to get the screen dimensions.